# SQL Server : aggregate function dilemma

Tags: sql-server, max

I have a table with columns `id`, `first`, `last`, `date_added`.

I want to get a list of all first names, and the most recent hire date for each first name, but I also want to get that employee's last name. Can't see to write a query that does this! I think I need to join to the same table?

My best attempt so far:

```
select 
    users.first, users.last, u2.date_added
from
    (select 
         first, max(date_added) as date_added
     from users
     group by first) u2
left join 
    users on u2.first = users.first
group by 
    users.first, users.last, u2.date_added
order by 
    users.first
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going by first name (which seems very curious), then I would recommend `row_number()`:

```
select u.first, u.last, u.date_added
from (select u.*, row_number() over (partition by first, date_added desc) as seqnum
      from users u
     ) u
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This pretty much worked! Had to make a slight modification but thank you so much for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your best attempt was close, but you need to join back to your max(date_added), as below

```
DECLARE @users TABLE
    (
        id int IDENTITY(1,1)
        , first varchar(100)
        , last varchar(100)
        , date_added datetime
    )

INSERT INTO @users
    (first
    ,last
    ,date_added
    )
    SELECT 'john', 'doe', GETDATE()
    UNION SELECT 'john', 'deere', DATEADD(d, 1, GETDATE())
    UNION SELECT 'jane', 'doe', GETDATE()

--actual data
SELECT * FROM @users

--desired output
SELECT 
    u.*
    FROM @users u
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT first, max(date_added) AS date_added_max
        FROM @users
        GROUP BY first
    ) max_u
    ON u.first = max_u.first
    AND u.date_added = max_u.date_added_max
ORDER BY u.first
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless I've misunderstood the question surely you just need to group the data? Example being:

```
select first, last, max(date_added) as date_added
from users
group by first, last
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood.

Comment: That gives me a list of more than I am looking for. So if my table has two entries for "Tom" (we'll say Tom Delonge - added 1/1/16 and Tom Hanks added 1/2/16), the result would show me both toms. I would only be looking for Tom Hanks, since he was most recently added